# How do you access the MySql data dictionary?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, information-schema

I am having trouble running this query.

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.routines;
```

The error code 3554 says

> Access to data dictionary table 'mysql.routines' is rejected.

I'm trying to look at all of my stored procedures. I've granted all privileges to the root user and it is still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for [the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA ROUTINES` Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/routines-table.html):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

From the documentation:

> The `ROUTINES` table provides information about stored routines (stored procedures and stored functions). The `ROUTINES` table does not include built-in SQL functions or user-defined functions (UDFs).

In normal cases, it is recommended to use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` instead of `mysql` schema : the former is the official interface to the system tables.